# How can I use from Setup Project

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project

The development phase of my project has been completed and now I want create a setup file.

What shoud I add in Application Folder in File System section ?

Where and how can I add my icon of project, database, recource and essential dll file?

Comment: So, you're asking how to make a setup project?  You see, the problem is that such a question is much too broad to answer.  You should start making one, then once you find a specific question about a single subject which you wish to find an answer to, come back and ask that.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, you add a setup project application to your solution.
Setup is a project type, so it's like adding another .exe.

Visual Studio has a wizard that takes you through most of the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Well if your question is like "How do I create a setup of my project?" You should try reading some of the tutorials on internet:

- [Creating Setup and Deployment Projects in VS.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vishnuprasad2005/SetupProjects12022005022406AM/SetupProjects.aspx)
- [Setup and Deployment with Prerequisites Included in VB.Net 2008](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/126557-setup-and-deployment-with-prerequisites-included-in-vbnet-2008/)
- [Serial Number in Setup and Deployment](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/137990-how-does-the-serial-number-in-setup-and-deployment-work/)